# Convert an entire DVD (with chapter menus) to Flash?

Tags: dvd, flash, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert DVD to a flash application (including menus)](https://superuser.com/questions/42130/convert-dvd-to-a-flash-application-including-menus)

I was recently asked to put a DVD onto a website - I ripped the chapters individually as MP4 files and created a nicely formatted playlist which lets you select the chapter you'd like, but apparently it's a really big requirement that the original DVD menus are preserved too. Agh.

I have no experience with using Flash or ActionScript whatsoever, and do not even have the software, so I was wondering if there is any software out there that could do this? I'm not too worried by cost as it'll presumably be cheaper than buying a copy of Flash anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the DVD was created in Flash, there is no telling what format it is in.

If it was created in Flash, try hunting down the original files or file maker and ask them to convert it (this will most likely be cheaper than purchasing software and/or time spent learning and converting).

However, if there isn't any videos/actions on the menu - I would just take screenshots and use old fashioned area links (e.g. [bottom of page here](http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/hyprlnks.html) ).

If there is videos/moving content, you are going to have one hell of a job - If you want to use Flash, I would use an easy to use tool such as [SoThink SWF Quicker](http://www.sothink.com/product/swfquicker/) (There used to be a really good one I used, but, I can't find the link anywhere :( )... You can probably do what you need within the trial period.

If you want it converted to anything other than flash - well,  I am not sure what is best for this and I have done my best to answer this question!

Answer (score 1):

Having no experience with the program but maybe following software would/could help you.
It is called  [Free Video to Flash Converter](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Video-to-Flash-Converter.htm).

Note: It wants to install also a Toolbar for your browser and a mailwasher.. I personaly would skip those! One of the advantages *It's free for both personal and commercial use.*

As William also said it is possible, maybe with help from more then just one programm but to do. Hope this helps you at least to the right direction, good luck.